# Understanding the difference between standardization and normalizing for hierarchical clustering

Tags: normalization, standardization, hierarchical-clustering, scales

I am trying to understand the difference between normalization and standardization for the hierarchical clustering.

I read the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) and some posts like [this](https://medium.com/@rrfd/standardize-or-normalize-examples-in-python-e3f174b65dfc) and [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/04/feature-scaling-machine-learning-normalization-standardization/) as well as several SO questions here.

In simple intuitive words my understanding is that

**Normalization** is necessary to make our data less sensitive to the scale of features

**Standardization** should be applied when we have different units or scales.

Moreover, almost everybody highlights that there is no rule of thumb and a universal approach.

I am trying to do the hierarchical clustering and have completely different results:

My data looks like hundreds of columns with daily numbers (probably something related to the financial market) for different companies.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

movements = pd.read_csv('movements.csv', index_col = 0)
movements_x = movements.values
```

**Option 1:**

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
movements_transformed = scaler.fit_transform(movements_x)

mergings = linkage(movements_transformed, method = 'ward')
labels = fcluster(mergings, 100, criterion = 'distance')
dendrogram(mergings, leaf_rotation = 90, leaf_font_size = 6)
plt.title("Movemements dataset: Clustering with Ward linkage method")
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Option 2:**

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(movements)
movements_normalized = normalize(X)

mergings = linkage(movements_normalized, method = 'ward')
dendrogram(mergings, labels = companies, leaf_rotation = 90, leaf_font_size = 9)
plt.title("Movemements dataset: Clustering with Ward linkage method")
plt.figure(figsize = (15, 12))
plt.show()
```

[image]

How to understand it more intuitively and which approach would be correct in my case?

Comment: it depends on what the daily financial numbers are. what are they

Comment: @develarist, not sure. The file is called movements and it looks like a daily change of something, what can be visualized as time series

Comment: you can't decide to standardize data if you don't even know what the data is. if it is showing the same variable for the different companies, then that means they are all being reported in the same units, meaning there is not much need to standardize. back to the first part though: what if the data *is* already standardized. you need to know what the data is

Comment: @develarist, thanks, makes sense, I will try to clarify!